# Returning to First Screen from last Screen in Mission Control

Tags: macos, spaces, mission-control

I use Mission Control (on a Mavericks running MacBook Air) a lot, and I was looking for a solution to the following scenario:

I have three (or more spaces open), and I am on the space furthest to the right (the last) in my lineup of spaces.  I want to get to my first space (the one furthest on the left).  Currently, if I try to go right from this last space, nothing happens. Is there a way that if I swipe right from the "last space", I can go directly to the "first space", and vice-versa?

Comment: So you want to go around the back ?

Comment: Yes, that's it.  (I couldn't think of a word for what I was trying to say, but that's it)

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know to do this is to 3- or 4-finger swipe up for Mission Control (depending on your settings) or use the keyboard shortcut (on my MBP it shares a key with F3), and then select the space that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried enabling keyboard shortcuts for directly accessing spaces by their number?

[image: SysPref>Keyboard]

No, this won't enable the wrap-around functionality that you specifically asked about, but it will allow you to type <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (control+1) to jump from space 3 to space 1.

You will need to press <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> if your Mac is set to use the function keys the default way.

Comment: Why use shortcuts when the mouse is so much more convenient. The question is - by swiping, let the swiping wrap around from last space back to first space. Not how to use shortcuts. Desktop space wrap-around is a convenient feature found in some multi-desktops apps in MICROSOFT WINDOWS. Have one way of doing it and doing it well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⬅︎</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>➜</kbd> to navigate between screens.  And if you've got a trackpad or Magic Mouse, you can enable "swipe between full screen apps" in SysPref to do the same at that @aglasser suggested

Comment: I'm using this method to swipe between screens, but I run into the problem enumerated in my question: to get from the last screen to the first, I have to swipe left through all of them.

Comment: yeah, I hear you. That sucks.  Maybe we can ask Apple to enable swipe rotation for spaces.  Seems like a no-brainer.  Or maybe we tell them that Android already has this feature.  THAT should get their attention! ;-)